# In asyncio module, how to break out of the event loop with variable we would like to continue with

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am new to the use of Asyncio module in python. Let's say there are two functions that I would like to run asynchronously. function_A() is basically running loop and that needs to be stopped at a certain condition with "if" statement.

I am unsure how eventloop works exactly, just knowing that when I run **loop.stop()**, it kills the kernel and restart it, so that the **"lst"** that I want to keep after breaking out of the eventloop will automatically be deleted after the kernel is killed.

Here is what I want to do:

```
global lst
lst = []

import asyncio
    async def function_A():        
        for i in range(0,100):
            lst.append(i)
            if len(lst) == 10:
               loop.stop()  #  <== this doesn't work well 

    async def function_B():
       # do something else

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.gather(function_A(), function_B())
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

## break out of the event loop ## 
# lst is saved and continue to another process with "lst"
```

Is there any way to do such work? A short example is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to return from a function, just use `return`. The `stop` method on the event loop is for stopping the processing of async tasks. It won't have effect on the task that is currently running, it will only prevent the event loop from executing **subsequent** tasks. Your loop doesn't await anything, so it doesn't allow for concurrent execution in the first place.

Comment: @user4815162342 did you mean placing `return` outside of the loop?

Comment: No, I mean the way to exit a function is by returning from it, `loop.stop` won't do it for you magically because it doesn't have that kind of power.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `loop.stop()` try using the `loop.close()`.

The following will just *stop* the loop.

> [loop.stop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop)
>
> Stop the event loop.

While the *close* will discard all the pending tasks as well.

> [loop.close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.close)
>
> Close the event loop.
>
> The loop must not be running when this function is called. Any pending
>   callbacks will be discarded.
>
> This method clears all queues and shuts down the executor, but does
>   not wait for the executor to finish.
>
> This method is idempotent and irreversible. No other methods should be
>   called after the event loop is closed.

Or you can return instead of calling the above functions and wait for `function_B` to return as well.
Only then **close** the loop.